# Javascript/Lodash/Redux - return object with specific id from an object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, lodash

So lets say we have an object:

```
names:
    {
     0: {"id": 30, name: "Adam"},
     1: {"id": 1, name: "Ben"},
     2: {"id": 15, name: "John"},
     ...
    }
```

and using lodash get function I want to save specific name into constant.

```
const name = _.get(state, ['names', nameId]);
```

I know this will not work because I'm selecting the key of the object not the id. Any idea how to fix it ? Note that I can't normalize the data like use the id as a key of the object because it ruins the order in which those data come from BE. Is it possible to loop through the object and look for the specific id ?

I'm getting the `nameId` correctely from other function

Comment: Does the answer **must use** lodash?

Comment: Do you mean you want to save the object the name is association with to the constant?

Comment: No it doesn't have to use lodash

Comment: if the nameId is lets say 30 then the name constant should have {"id": 30, name: "Adam"} inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for Lodash. Just loop through the object's properties looking for a match on `id`:

```js
const names = {
 0: {"id": 30, name: "Adam"},
 1: {"id": 1, name: "Ben"},
 2: {"id": 15, name: "John"}
};
const nameId = 1;
let obj;
for (const name in names) {
  if (names[name].id == nameId) {
    obj = names[name];
    break;
  }
}
console.log(obj);
```

Or using `Object.keys` and `some`, but it doesn't really buy you anything other than skipping inherited properties:

```js
const names = {
 0: {"id": 30, name: "Adam"},
 1: {"id": 1, name: "Ben"},
 2: {"id": 15, name: "John"}
};
const nameId = 1;
let obj;
Object.keys(names).some(name => {
  if (names[name].id == nameId) {
    obj = names[name];
    return true;
  }
});
console.log(obj);
```

Or using ES2017's [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) *(which is easily polyfilled for older environments)* and `find`:

```js
const names = {
 0: {"id": 30, name: "Adam"},
 1: {"id": 1, name: "Ben"},
 2: {"id": 15, name: "John"}
};
const nameId = 1;
const obj = Object.values(names).find(entry => entry.id == nameId);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.find()` with `_.values()` to get specific object by **id**.

```js
var state = {names:{
  0: {"id": 30, name: "Adam"},
  1: {"id": 1, name: "Ben"},
  2: {"id": 15, name: "John"},
}}

var r = _.find(_.values(state.names), {id: 1})
console.log(r)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple approach

```
var output = Object.values( obj.names ).find( function( item ){ return item.id = inputId }).name;
```

- Iterate the object values' array by using `Object.values`
- Use `find` to get specific value by doing `id` comparison
- Get `name` property of the returned object.

**Demo**

```js
var obj = {
    names: {
        0: {"id": 30, name: "Adam"},
        1: {"id": 1, name: "Ben"},
        2: {"id": 15, name: "John"}
    }
};   
var inputId = 15;
console.log( Object.values( obj.names ).find( function( item ){ return item.id = inputId }).name );
```